# Accessing a dictionary key by its index

Tags: c++-cli

It's probably an easy question but how do I access the value of a dictionary key in a specific row.
Let's say `Dict` is `{ 1,13; 3,14; 5,17 }` 
The second key is `3`.

How do I get that value? 
I tried `Dict->Key[2]` but gave an error and can't find a reference to it

Update:
This gives me what I need but maybe there is a faster way.

```
 Dictionary<double, double>::KeyCollection^ keyColl = Dict->Keys;

 double first;
 double last;

  int counter=0;
  int dictionaryCount = Dict->Count;
for each( double s in keyColl )
{
if(counter==0){
    first=s;
}
if(dictionaryCount == counter+1){
    last=s;
}
//Dict[first] would be the first key
//Dict[last] would be the last key
```

Comment: I think it depends on how the dictionary is implemented, because it may re-arrange the rows to make lookups faster

Comment: Basically I need the value of the key in row 1, row 2, row 3.
So I need 1, 3, 5 returned as values.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered (hash tables), or self ordering (btrees). Show us your code we know what type you are working with.

Comment: The dictionary is Dict<double,double>

Comment: You can use `OrderedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Dictionary<> class has an *indexer*, you use it by applying the `[]` operator directly to the object reference.  It is named `Item` in the MSDN Library articles.  The indexer for Dictionary takes a key and returns the value for the key.  Sample code:

```
auto dict = gcnew Dictionary<int, double>();
dict->Add(1, 13);
dict->Add(3, 14);
dict->Add(5, 17);
auto value = dict[3];
```

You could use the TryGetValue() method instead if you are not sure if the key is present.

> The dictionary is `Dict<double,double>`

Do beware that using *double* as the key is **very** troublesome.  Comparing floating point values for equality is filled with surprises, none of them good ones.  You must use the `Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<>)` constructor and pass your own comparer to have any hope of surviving this.  Ask another question about that if necessary.

Comment: I need to get the key in the 2nd entry not the value

Comment: A dictionary is not an ordered collection, there is no notion of a "2nd entry".  A List<> is an ordered collection.